# How do I reset a git branch to a given previous commit and fix the detached HEAD?

Tags: git

I needed to reset my branch to an earlier working state (commit) so I did:

```
git reset --hard c70e611
```

Now I see

```
HEAD detached at c70e611
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

How to fix / understand / get around the detached head message and push so that c70e611 is now the latest commit I am using and represents the HEAD of the branch I am working in (not master).

Comment: See: http://gitfaq.org/articles/what-is-a-detached-head.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `HEAD detached at c70e611`

This is because when you did the `git reset --hard`, you were not on any branch at that time. You had a detached `HEAD`, and that detached head got moved with the `git reset --hard` command, along with a rewrite of your working tree to that state.

If you want some branch `foo` to be `c70611`, then:

```
git checkout foo
git reset --hard c70611
```

If this is considered to be a good state to push to `foo`'s upstream then just `git push <remote-name> foo`.

There is a more direct way to force `foo` to `c70611` without checking it out to be the current branch. Namely, you can rewrite what `foo` points to using the `git update-ref` command.

Before doing any of the above, I would pause and try to see how I had ended up in a detached state without noticing. Perhaps it was an unfinished rebase or whatever. Step one is to review the last few entries in the `git reflog` to help jog your memory.

Comment: If the current HEAD commit isn't an ancestor of a branch, wouldn't the first command discard the commit HEAD is on?

Answer (score 6):

`HEAD` is where your workspace is currently in the tree of `git` commits; `detached` means that it doesn't correspond to a branch. To fix this, you should create a new branch with `git checkout -b branch` (replacing `branch` with the name you want to give your new branch).

If you want to drop the commits following the one you reset to, you can delete the master branch and re-create it:

```
git branch -D master
git checkout -b master
```

If you're working on a repository which is pushed elsewhere you'll need to do more work to fix things up, possibly forcing a push (and telling every one else to re-clone their workspace). If you have shared state, you should really create a revert commit; take a look at `git revert` (starting from `master` and reverting all the commits starting with the one following `c70e611`).

Comment: Is it possible to do this in one command?